How can I unzip an .apkm file in windows 11?
Im trying to install an .apkm file through adb in windows 11, for example:
 .\adb install "C:\Users\aes12\Downloads\com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox_15.32.37.28.arm-301381721_6dpi_1feat_d6ce31e208513f475be14d3c76d6ae3d_apkmirror.com.apkm"

I get the error:

adb.exe: filename doesn't end .apk or .apex

I understand that .apkm files are essentially a zip bundled .apk files. I've also found that I can use,  .\adb install-multiple (get-item *.apk) to install multiple .apk's. However I need to unzip the .apkm file first before I run the command. How can I do that in windows 11 through power  shell?
